# How Can I Get A LaTex Table Generated By R's MonteCarlo Package To Work?

Tags: tables, packages, r

I have been experimenting with the MonteCarlo package in R for a project. After using the maketable function, I was given the following code to generate a LaTex table with the Monte Carlo simulation's results.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\resizebox{ 1 \textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{ rrrrrrrrr }
\hline\hline\\\\
scale & n/loc &  & 0 & 0.2 & 0.4 & 0.6 & 0.8 & 1 \\ 
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
\multirow{ 4 }{*}{ 1 } & 50 &  & 0.06 & 0.31 & 0.80 & 0.99 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ 
 & 100 &  & 0.06 & 0.54 & 0.98 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ 
 & 250 &  & 0.05 & 0.89 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ 
 & 500 &  & 0.04 & 0.99 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ 
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
\multirow{ 4 }{*}{ 2 } & 50 &  & 0.05 & 0.11 & 0.33 & 0.59 & 0.81 & 0.93 \\ 
 & 100 &  & 0.05 & 0.14 & 0.52 & 0.83 & 0.97 & 1.00 \\ 
 & 250 &  & 0.05 & 0.36 & 0.89 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ 
 & 500 &  & 0.06 & 0.66 & 0.99 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ 
\\
\\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{ decision  }
\end{table}
```

This code had numerous error messages when I try to compile it in Texstudio. Browsing around the forum, I found that by adding a \documentclass{article} and \begin{document}. command at the beginning with the appropriate \end commands at the end, a majority of the errors resolved themselves. However, I still have five errors that are popping up in the editor that are preventing compilation. Those errors are:

```
line 5 - Undefined control sequence. \resizebox
line 5 - Missing number, treated as zero. \resizebox { 1 \ textwidth}
line 5 - Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \resizebox { 1 \ textwidth}
line 10 - Undefined control sequence. \multirow
line 15 - Undefined control sequence. \multirow
```

Any ideas about how I can resolve these errors would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE. I encourage you to read a tutorial on  `RStudio`, `knitr`, and `Markdown`, like this one: https://github.com/sahirbhatnagar/knitr-tutorial. The home of all things on `knitr` is here: https://yihui.name/knitr/.

First, in `RStudio`, you need to create a file with an `.Rnw` extension. This file includes your `LaTeX` code, and chunks of `R` code. Compile the file with `pdfLaTeX` or `XeLaTeX`. This will execute your code chunks, the output from which will be included in a `.tex` file together with any `LaTeX` formatting instructions you may have given. The product is a `pdf` file that includes the output of any `LaTeX` code you have written together with the output of executing the `R` code.

All you have at the moment is a code fragment for including in a `.tex` file that you need to write. That file will start with `\documentclass{article}` (or some other class like `book` or `report`) and end with `\end{document}`.

Here is an example, let's call it `Fledgling.Rnw` from one of [@Fran's great answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/509968/):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<mytable,echo=FALSE,results='asis'>>=
library(xtable)
a <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),nrow=3)
xtable(a)
@
\end{document}
```

The `R` code chunk is placed between `<<>>==` and `@`. Here, it loads `xtable`. `library` is the equivalent of `\usepackage` in `LaTeX`. A matrix, `a`, is created, which is then formatted using `LaTeX` syntax by executing `xtable`. A file called `Fledling.tex` will be created at the conclusion of executing the `R` code. This is made possible using the `R` package, `knitr`. No user intervention is required. All you need is RStudio and a `.Rnw` file. With the `.tex` file created, `pdfLaTeX` or `XeLaTeX` take over and compile `Fledgling.tex` to produce `Fledgling.pdf`.

Answer (score 3):

You need the `graphicx` package for `\resizebox` and the `multirow` package for `\multirow`, so this works:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\resizebox{ 1 \textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{ rrrrrrrrr }
\hline\hline\\\\
scale & n/loc &  & 0 & 0.2 & 0.4 & 0.6 & 0.8 & 1 \\ 
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
\multirow{ 4 }{*}{ 1 } & 50 &  & 0.06 & 0.31 & 0.80 & 0.99 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ 
 & 100 &  & 0.06 & 0.54 & 0.98 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ 
 & 250 &  & 0.05 & 0.89 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ 
 & 500 &  & 0.04 & 0.99 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ 
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
\multirow{ 4 }{*}{ 2 } & 50 &  & 0.05 & 0.11 & 0.33 & 0.59 & 0.81 & 0.93 \\ 
 & 100 &  & 0.05 & 0.14 & 0.52 & 0.83 & 0.97 & 1.00 \\ 
 & 250 &  & 0.05 & 0.36 & 0.89 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ 
 & 500 &  & 0.06 & 0.66 & 0.99 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ 
\\
\\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{ decision  }
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

That said, I think resizing that table is a bit pointless, so I would rather do something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ rrrrrrrrr }
\toprule
scale & n/loc &  & 0 & 0.2 & 0.4 & 0.6 & 0.8 & 1 \\ \midrule
\multirow{ 4 }{*}{ 1 } & 50 &  & 0.06 & 0.31 & 0.80 & 0.99 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ 
 & 100 &  & 0.06 & 0.54 & 0.98 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ 
 & 250 &  & 0.05 & 0.89 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ 
 & 500 &  & 0.04 & 0.99 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ \addlinespace
\multirow{ 4 }{*}{ 2 } & 50 &  & 0.05 & 0.11 & 0.33 & 0.59 & 0.81 & 0.93 \\ 
 & 100 &  & 0.05 & 0.14 & 0.52 & 0.83 & 0.97 & 1.00 \\ 
 & 250 &  & 0.05 & 0.36 & 0.89 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ 
 & 500 &  & 0.06 & 0.66 & 0.99 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\caption{ decision  }
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The `booktabs` package provides the macros `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule` and `\addlinespace`.

Comment: Obviously, if the table changes from time to time, editing the code isn't ideal.