# How do I insert a CFA output from R into Latex using lavaan and semTable?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am not very experienced when it comes to Latex or R. As said in the title, I have a CFA output I generated with R Studio and now want to insert into Latex. Unfortunately, whenever I do this, my document in Latex no longer compiles.
This is my current code. As you can see I tried multiple packages (stargazer, xtable, semTable) without success so far.

```
install.packages("semTable")
install.packages("kutils")
library(semTable)
library(kutils)
biimodell <- "Bl=~B1+B2+B3+B4+B5+B6+B7+B8+B9
Ha=~H1+H2+H3+H4+H5+H6+H7+H8+H9+H10"
biifit <- cfa(model=biimodell, data=d, orthogonal=TRUE)
summary(biifit, fit.measures=TRUE, standardized=TRUE)
cfaTable(biifit)
semTable(biifit)
xtable(biifit)
stargazer(biifit)
apa_print(biifit)$estimate$modelfit
compareLavaan(biifit, fitmeas = c("rmsea",
                                  "cfi"))

semTable(biifit, paramSets = "all",
         columns = c(est = "Estimate", se = "SE", z = "z", p = "p"), fits = c("chisq", "cfi", "tli", "rmsea"),
         type = "latex", alpha = c(0.05, 0.01, 0.001))
```

Comment: Most of us won't have R installed. Can you post the content of the generated table? Did you look at the R package description that generates the table which LaTeX packages it requires? I checked the documentation, the package has a `testtable` command. Try this and see a) if it can be compiled and b) which packages it uses.

Comment: (1) That R code as is not compilable (where is the function cfa, for instance, maybe is that of the not loaded package lavaan?), so nobody can know what kind of output are you trying to insert (2) There are not any latex code, so nobody can know where are trying to insert the output. (3) Run a R script ant the insert output in LaTeX is the wrong hard way. The right (easy) way is `knitr`.  A very simple  example of use [hrere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/509968/11604).